# KaTeX's official starter-template not working

Tags: javascript, html, katex

I inserted a very simply body into the [KaTeX starter-template](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html), however, it doesn't work. Why is that? What do I need to do to render the body?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- KaTeX requires the use of the HTML5 doctype. Without it, KaTeX may not render properly -->
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- The loading of KaTeX is deferred to speed up page rendering -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-g7c+Jr9ZivxKLnZTDUhnkOnsh30B4H0rpLUpJ4jAIKs4fnJI+sEnkvrMWph2EDg4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- To automatically render math in text elements, include the auto-render extension: -->
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-mll67QQFJfxn0IYznZYonOWZ644AWYC+Pt2cHqMaRhXVrursRwvLnLaebdGIlYNa" crossorigin="anonymous"
        onload="renderMathInElement(document.body);"></script>
  </head>

<body>



    <p>1</p>
    <p>Inline math $p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$ is what this is</p>
    
    <p>2</p>
    <p>$\begin{aligned}
       x &= 2\
         &= \frac{3}{2}
    \end{aligned}$
    </p>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [unminified version](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.js) of the code I've found the default settings that are applied. The following delimeters should be used:

- `$$`
- `\\(`
- `\\)`
- `\\[`
- `\\]`

I was able to make the first formula work by changing `$` to `$$` on both sides of the formula.

```
<p>1</p>
<p>Inline math $$p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$ is what this is</p>
```

I was able to make the second formula work by changing `$` to `$$` on both sides and adding  `\\` to the end of each line.

```
<p>2</p>
<p>$$\begin{aligned} \\
  x &= 2\ \\
  &= \frac{3}{2} \\
  \end{aligned}$$
</p>
```